# Propositional Logic - List of N integers

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Today in our propositional-calculus class, we were asked this question:

> Suppose you have a list of N integers: you write a computer program to
> analyze the list. If every integer in the list is greater than 10,
> then the returned output is the value TRUE. Else, the output is the
> value FALSE. If N = 0, and therefore, the list is empty, what is the
> output?

While explaining how to interpret the problem, my teacher said that the returned value is FALSE, because, since the list is empty, there aren't any counterexamples against that statement.

I didn't seem to grasp that. First of all, isn't the else statement a condition in itself? Namely, the condition:

> If there's at least one number less than (or equal to) 10 [...]

There aren't any counterexamples to that either, so why favouring a condition over the other?
Honestly, my solution (as wrong as it may be) would be to claim that the expressed conditions simply do not cover the "empty list" case, so the output value cannot be determined with the information we possess.

Otherwise, is the "else" to be interpreted as "in every other case"? In this eventuality, the output would be FALSE, but to be fair, I'm not sure of this answer.

So, what is the solution?

Comment: I don't understand.  The absence of counterexamples means a statement is True.  To be sure, it is equally true that every element of $\emptyset$ is $≤10$, again because there are no counterexamples.

Comment: That was exactly my doubt, I'm sorry if I had trouble communicating that. So, if there are no counterexamples to both statements, are the 2 conditions not enough to cover the case in which the list is empty? Meaning that, in this case, we cannot decide whether the output would be true or false.

Comment: When you speak of the output of some particular code or pseudo-code it obviously depends on the code itself.  I took your question to be "is the proposition True when $N=0$" to which I would say "Yes.  The proposition is vacuously True because there are no counterexamples to it."

Comment: In practice, people often prove Theorems, even hard Theorems, about sets which might prove to be empty.  Nothing wrong with that.  For example, there are many good theorems about odd perfect numbers (even though there may well be no such things).  Those Theorems would still be True though, even if it turns out they only concern the empty sret.

Comment: Oh, I see now. And the opposite proposition "There's at least one number less than or equal to 10" is false, since of course there are no elements at all. Now it makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Oh yes, that statement is false for $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your teacher just got muddled with which output represents what. If there are is a counterexample to the statement "every integer in the list is greater than 10", it should output FALSE. Since there can't be a counterexample, it should output TRUE. So the reasoning is correct, but your teacher has linked it to the other output, presumably by mistake.

FWIW if I was to program this in python, it would look like

```
def all_greater(mylist):
    for x in mylist:
        if x<10:
            return False
    return True
```

This will return True if the list is empty, because the loop will execute 0 times.